# Navigation 5 'focus' listener not triggered when app is brought back up from background

Tags: android, ios, react-native, use-effect, react-navigation-v5

I am using `React Navigation` 5, and I am trying to set up a focus listener on a Screen to perform some actions.
The `Screen` where I need to set up the listener is a `Class` component that triggers the browser launch, and I want to listen to when the user closes the browser with the "back navigation" and return to the app.

**While testing this flow I noticed that the listener is not triggered when returning from the browser, or even when coming up from the background**. On the other hand, I could successfully test that when navigating between screens within the app everything works as expected.
Moreover, I set up also the unsubscriber for the focus listener and I can see that it's not called improperly, and the listener still seems alive.

I searched for other issues, questions on SO, read the docs, but I couldn't find a solution. It's also true that I'm a newbie as long as React Native is concerned, but I would expect that the focus listener is triggered also after putting the app to background.
Or is there actually a way to achieve that?

I managed to create a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@bigmec87/repro-navigation-focus) with a sample code (my app is not using Expo CLI, but I saw that the issue is correctly reproduced there too).
It's a very simple StackNavigator with 2 screens. `Screen1` is the `Class` component in which I want to listen for the focus.

1. by pressing the "GO TO BROWSER" button, the Google website is opened, but navigating back to the app no logs appear informing that the focus is on;
2. going to background and getting the app back up no logs appear for the focus;
3. by pressing the "GO TO SCREEN 2" button, the second screen is opened, and upon back navigation, the focus test log informs us that the focus is now on.

**My software versions:**

iOS and Android 12.4.7 and API 29&24
@react-navigation/native    5.5.1
@react-navigation/stack 5.5.1
react-native-gesture-handler    1.6.1
react-native-safe-area-context  3.0.5
react-native-screens    2.8.0
react-native    0.62.2
node    12.17.0
npm 6.14.6

Comment: focus listener doesn't worked for app background/foreground. You will need to add AppState listener for that. https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate In some very old android phones, this too doesn't triggers sometimes when coming back to the app from an activity(browser in your case) your app launched

Comment: [Maxim Bodrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11876198) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66836345) saying "I faced the same issue. I found out this post [https://rossbulat.medium.com/working-with-app-state-and-event-listeners-in-react-native-ffa9bba8f6b7](https://rossbulat.medium.com/working-with-app-state-and-event-listeners-in-react-native-ffa9bba8f6b7) I believe it will help you"